# how to get another plist?

Tags: ios4

i accidentally deleted the original plist file that comes with the template for an app. how do i get it back? the app isn't 'building and going'. Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you didn't perform any customization to the plist, then the simplest way would be to create a new application with the same name and type as your application (in a different folder on your machine).  This will generate the default plist file for the application as before.  You can then either copy that plist file into your original project or create a new plist called -Info.plist in your original project and duplicate all the entries that were created in the dummy application you just created.